# Шахматы на delphi

Tags: delphi

Добрый вечер! Не могу понять, что не так...Код вроде написан верно, но шахматное поле не показывается на форме...

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
Timer1: TTimer;
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;
Buf, Pole: TBitmap;
img: array[1..12] of TBitmap;
map: array[0..7,0..7] of integer;
way: array[0..7,0..7] of Boolean;
Current: integer;
path: string;
Activ: Tpoint;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
i, j: integer;
begin
path:=ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
for i:=1 to 12 do;
begin
img[i]:=TBitmap.Create;
img[i].Transparent:=True;
img[i].LoadFromFile(path+'\img\'+inttostr(i)+'.bmp');

end;

pole:=TBitmap.Create;
pole.LoadFromFile(path+'\img\pole.bmp');

Buf:=TBitmap.Create;
Buf.Width:=640;
Buf.Height:=480;

Current:=1;
Activ.X:=-1;
Activ.Y:=-1;


for j:=1 to 12 do;
for j:=1 to 12 do;
begin
map[i, j]:=0;
way[i, j]:=false;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

Buf.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Pole);
form2.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Buf);
end;

end.
```

Comment: В таком виде код достаточно трудно читать. Не могли бы вы его отформатировать (отступы правильные сделать)? Наверняка ваша IDE умеет делать это автоматически.

Comment: покажите значение Timer1.interval и укажите сколько вы ждали ответ.

Answer (score 1):

I. Интересная конструкция кода:

```
for i := 1 to 12 do;
begin
  img[i]:=TBitmap.Create;
  img[i].Transparent:=True;
  img[i].LoadFromFile(path+'\img\'+inttostr(i)+'.bmp');
end;
```

В таком случае у нас выражение превращается в

```
for i := 1 to 12 do
begin
end;

begin
  img[i]:=TBitmap.Create;
  img[i].Transparent:=True;
  img[i].LoadFromFile(path+'\img\'+inttostr(i)+'.bmp');
end;
```

После конструкции for  to <> do не нужно ставить знак - **;** (точку с запятой) потому что выражение которое будет ниже не будет относится к циклу.

II. Нужно будет использовать другую переменную в цикле. Поскольку у нас уже 2 зависимых цикла - будет ошибка E2081 Assignment to FOR-Loop variable 'j' .

```
for i:=1 to 12 do
  for j:=1 to 12 do
```

III. Если задачу свести к минимуму - получится что то такое:

```
var 
  Pole: TBitmap;
  path: string;
begin
  Pole := TBitmap.Create;
  Try
    path := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    Pole.LoadFromFile(path + '\img\pole.bmp');

    form1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Pole);
  finally
      FreeAndNil(Pole);
  end;
end;
```

Это пример с одноразовой загрузкой изображения, отрисовкой и удалением объекта.
Как включить отображение утечек памяти [можно ознакомится тут](http://mirsovetov.net/show-memory-leek.html)

IV. Используйте по минимуму глобальные переменные и по возможности выносите код в другие классы, переименовывайте стандартные компоненты.

Answer (score -1):

сделайте

```
Timer1.enabled = True;
```